# Stop HttpClient execution on Timeout

Tags: android, android-asynctask, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm executing a Http request using `HttpClient` using post method on an `AsyncTask`, but I want to cancel the execution in case the user's internet connection is slow. Is there a way to stop an `HttpClient.execute(post)` after 10 seconds and throw an exception?

Comment: i guess you can have a connection time out for your http request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 1);
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

then do your request using that client